# CsvBulkLoader for SiteTree objects

Tags: csv, silverstripe, bulkloader

I'm trying to use a custom CsvBulkLoader loader to create Pages, however the loader isn't working proprely. If I use a subclass of SiteTree it tells me method parent() is not avaiable on the class. I tried writing directly to SiteTree then changing the instance to the Target class on the last write, but the Content disappears.

```
protected function processRecord($record, $columnMap, &$results, $preview = false)
{
    $post = BlogPost::create();

    $post->update($record);

    $post->writeToStage('Stage');


    $post->publish("Stage", "Live");

    return $post->ID;
}
```

Comment: Are you setting a `ParentID` to an existing `Blog` page ID in your CSV file? Looking through the `BlogPost` class code `Parent()` is used throughout the code. I think `BlogPost` requires a parent `Blog` page for it to be saved.

Comment: Yes I'm doing a SiteTree::get_by_link() to set the ParentID manually

Comment: The content issue ended up being a problem with another module, however it still doesn't explain the Parent Issue. I ended up saving it as Blank draft as as a SiteTree, the changing the class instance and adding the content before publishing.